Objectbox Relations: Updating/deleting toMany automatically when updating/deleting Object
I have 3 questions about using the toMany Relations with the objectbox database. Assumed that I have a tvchannels entity:
@Entity
data class TvChannel(
        @Id var id: Long = 0,
        var name: String? = "",
    var epgChId: String? = ""
)
{
    lateinit var epgData: ToMany<EpgData>
} 

and a EpgData entity:
data class EpgData(
        @Id var id: Long = 0,
        var name: String? = "",
    var epgChId: String? = "",
    var epgSourceId: Long? = null,
    var date: String? = "",
    var startTimeStamp: Long? = null,
    var stopTimeStamp: Long? = null
)

Adding EpgData to tv channels with:
for (chann in channels) {
val epg = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    epgDataBox.query(EpgData_.epgChId.equal(chann.epgChId)
       .and(EpgData_.date.equal(todayDateString)))
       .build().find()
  }
chann.epgData.addAll(epg)
tvChannBox.put(chann)
}


When different channels can have the same epgChId / the same EpgData, when should I add also

@Backlink(to = "epgData")
 lateinit var tvchannels: ToMany<TvChannel>

to the EpgData Entity? It is not indispensable, correct?

Assuming the user changes the timeoffset of the epgSource and every startTimeStamp & stopTimeStamp property of the EpgData Objects with the related epgSourceId (of the changed EpgSource) will be adjusted and updated.
Whats with the epgData from the TvChannel Entity? As it is only a relation to the EpgData I suppose that the TvChannel then uses the updated timestamps, correct?

Main question: What happens when an EpgData object is deleted from the database. For example I want to delete old EpgData from the database (date older then 3 days).
It isn't automatically deleted from epgData in the TvChannel Entity or? So if a deleted Object is part of a toMany-relation, it still exists there?
If yes, what would be the best way to remove deleted Objects also in the relations?


Problem: Lets say there are 20.000 EpgData Objects to delete and I have 500 tv channels (add. multiple channels use the same EpgData objects relation). When I have to iterate throw all channels and remove the deleted EpgData step by step, its quiet a large amount of data to check / remove. Is there a simple or easier way to do this? Or is @Backlink the solution for this?
Thanks in advance, hopefully one of the objectbox experts can help a beginner hobby developer.


The backlink property is optional. It is based on an actually existing relation.

The relation is based on object IDs. So yes, the target objects will have updated data when the object owning the relation is get afterwards.

If an object is removed, it is also removed from all relations it was pointed to.



Side note: for more details on backlinks, see https://docs.objectbox.io/relations#one-to-many-1-n and following.

Hallo Uwe sorry, became father this week so I had no time to response :) thanks for your clear answers. Referring to 2 I have an additional question: Asume I have an entity TvCategory that has a lateninit var channels: toMany<TvChannel>. As the documentation says on first access of a specific tvcategory (when a tvcategory is focused I call tvcategory.channels) the data is loaded from DB and cached in memory. Let's say I have 20 categories loaded, and I change something on the channels, how can i "refresh" the data of all already loaded tvcategory.channels? reset() on each? and then?

Congratulations! As for ToMany: call channels.reset() and then access the channels list again, like via a get.

Thank you :) But theoretically it would be also enough to call (for an already accessed tvCategory) f.e. val updatedChannels = tvCategoryA.channels and set tvChannelsAdapter.submitlist(updatedChannels) to get the updated channels data in the recyclerview, so call reset() in that case wouldn't be necessary, do I understand that right?

No: If it's the same ToMany instance it will still have the same list of cached objects. Either reset the ToMany first, then it will reload the objects when its list is accessed in any way. Or get the object that contains the ToMany from its Box again, to get a fresh ToMany instance. Hope that helps?

All right, got it, now it works as I want, thank you very much. One last question: If TvChannel has a toOne relation to the EpgChannel entity and EpgChannel has a toMany relation to Epgdata and I have already accessed it via tvchannel.epgchannel.target.epgdatalist. The EPG data is then updated. To get the updated EPG data for the tvchannel, is it enough to apply reset() to the related EpgChannel and call tvchannel.epgchannel.target.epgdatalist again, correct?

Sure. But honestly, as with all business logic I just recommend to write unit tests for this to ensure it works as intended.
